# Launching 'Profile' for keyboard extension

Tags: ios, xcode, profile, ios-keyboard-extension

In 'Product' menu there is a 'Profile' item, but it is unavailable for **keyboard extension**.
Does anybody know how I can profile the keyboard extention?